# Why no exception occur on a wrong LINQ query in a task (query never ends in a task)

Tags: c#, .net, linq

The code below fails because of Null Exception.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> ints = null;

        int a = ints.Where(x => x == 10).Single();
    }
```

---

But this code never ends and no exception

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(() => Method());
    }

    public static async Task Method()
    {
        List<int> ints = null;

        int a = ints.Where(x => x == 10).Single();
    }
```

Why does nothing happen in second code? 
What is going on?
Would you please explain it in a deep detail.

Comment: Because it's internal task exception https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537614(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: We can't give you a full-fledged course on async programming here. Fortunately we don't have to because there is one: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: @GertArnold thanks. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You started a task. The task ran your method. You never cared for results, so you never got notified when your method threw an exception either. Try this to actually see what happens when you *do* care for the results, like you would do in a real program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Method().Result);
}

public static async Task<int> Method()
{
    List<int> ints = null;

    int a = ints.Where(x => x == 10).Single();

    return a;
}
```

Comment: thanks. but the exception happens in the main method that says **One or more errors occurred**.

Comment: @qazwsx123 If you want to catch your exception inside your task, you need a `try`/`catch` block inside your task.